# Migration of LUIS account failed

Tags: migration, azure-language-understanding

I cannot access my LUIS models nor can complete the migration on eu.luis.ai.
Error message is:
Migration of your account has failed. Here is a list of possible reasons why:
You created a resource using an invalid account name.
Your role lacks sufficient permissions to create Azure resources on your Azure subscription.

- I could create on Azure portal a LUIS resource with my account.
- I cannot access my models on [www.luis.ai](http://www.luis.ai) any more, because I do not have a valid subscription for this region.
- I migrated my account already a few months back to the new Authoring key successfully (and am wondering why another migration should be done)
- I cannot create a new authoring resource from the LUIS portal, nor migrate using one of the existing keys I can select.
- Using previous LUIS experience does not help neither.
- I have a lot of models partially from the initial days of LUIS
- We are using keys with "_" in the name, which is not supported any more. But new key names without underscore are not accepted neither.

I cannot imagine that I am the only one with this problem. In one of our client migrations we could do the migration by deleting all models and then do the migration successfully. But as I have no access to the models any more this is no option for me.

I assume something went wrong in the backend of LUIS portal because the error message presented cannot be true.

[image: Screenshot LUIS Migration]

Comment: Now I could access my models on westus again using the old portal: https://previous.luis.ai/applications. A retry on https://previous.eu.luis.ai returned: 
A server error occured. Please refresh the page and try again.

Comment: Did you resolve it ? I have the same problem, I notice that the request https://api.luis.ai/webApi/v2.0/user/termsOfUse return a status code 500 into the microsoft website when you click to continue

Answer (score 0):

@Klaus, make sure you selected the correct tenant (your profile > Switch directory)

Comment: That was done already. I have seen that you have to select the tenant every time after logging in. In other tenants I do have the same issue. I could create a new LUIS resource, got a positive message, that migration has succeeded, but with "Continue" the migration failed again with the same error message as above.Meanwhile a ticket is open at Microsoft an logs sent to support.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has applied a hot fix today and access is working again. Hope, for everybody else, too! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If your LUIS models or services where created with a location in Europe (i.e westeurope) use this site [eu.luis.ai](https://eu.luis.ai/).

Answer (score 0):

To point out, this problem occurs when you use wrong luis.ai site.

So when I have my Azure Language Understanding Authoring resource in West Europe and I accidentally used https://luis.ai site, this error occurred. But when I went to https://eu.luis.ai everything works fine.

So check that your Cognitive Services resource's Resource Location matches the luis.ai portal you use!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-regions